# Limit Number of Parameters a Javascript Function Accepts

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

How to limit the number of parameters a Javascript function accepts?

So that this snippet only logs each value not including the index and the array:

```js
const names = ["John", "Jack", "Jake"]

names
.map(console.log)
```

Comment: btw, `map` is returning a new array. in this case `forEach` would fit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't provide a clear cut way to limit the number of parameters a function accepts.

However, you can accomplish this by wrapping the original function in an arrow function likeso:

```js
const log1 = first => console.log(first)
const log2 = (first, second) => console.log(first, second)
// ...

const names = ["John", "Jack", "Jake"]

names
.map(log1)
```

A slightly more reusable and scalable approach would be to create a limitParams function which limits the number of parameters a given function accepts to the specified number:

```js
const limitParams = n => f => (...params) => f(...params.slice(0, n))

const log1 = limitParams(1)(console.log)
const log2 = limitParams(2)(console.log)
// ...

const names = ["John", "Jack", "Jake"]

names
.map(log1)
```

Comment: This would make it impossible to change `this` in the wrapped function, as the arrow function forbids it. To be more correct, it should be using normal functions `function limitParameters(n) { return function(f) { return function() { return f.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, n))} } }`

Comment: That's a great variation if the function you are limiting refers to 'this' inside it's body, which is often the case in OOP code. However I like the functional approach of simply parameterizing everything and keeping functions isolated and pure. In my opinion it's easier to understand and maintain, but then again it depends on your style.

Comment: While I agree with pure functions, the fact is that JS does use `this` and by obliterating it, you are possibly breaking some contracts. You could, for example, be changing `this` by using the second parameter of an iteration method - `someArray.forEach(myFunction, newThis)`

Comment: It is perhaps the 'Javascript way' of doing things, but no one forces you to ever use this. You'd definitely have to make sure that you and your team are on the same page in terms of styles. Once you pick one for a project, make sure to stick to it. You might find this video interesting as Mark discusses related topics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=US8QG9I1XW0.